# What is mean by build in definition of software industry?

Tags: mobile, web, build

Usually we are using the term "Build" in mobile which means the developer can compile their code and convert source code into executable form.

But in WEB what is the definition of this?

Answer (score 2):

In a programming context, a build is a version of a program.

As a rule, a build is a pre-release version and as such is identified by a build number, rather than by a release number.

Reiterative (repeated) builds are an important part of the development process, and they are known as [Continuous Integration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_integration).

Throughout development, application components are collected and repeatedly compiled for testing purposes, to ensure a reliable final product.

Build tools, such as make, Ant, [Maven](http://maven.apache.org/), enable developers to automate some programming tasks.